# Can FireFox's native `view-source:` schema for ANY text file be restored?

Tags: bash, firefox

FireFox's native `view-source:` schema seems to be have been crippled.

Perversely, this would even render binary file URL's when prefaced with `view-source:`.

This was very convenient for quick perusal of `file:` URI schemas of directories containing textual source code from within FF (especially with a single new tab right click rendering), a main reason I have endorsed FF as the browser of choice in the past. This would render human readable textual sources across the board, whether "executable" sources such as `.sh, .bat, .c, .fortran, .perl, .tcl, ...` as well as "ordinary" `.csv, .txt, .dat, ...` files.

```
     data:text/plain,testing
     view-source:data:text/plain,testing
```

As an aside the `view-source:view-source:view-source:` of some `.html` URI source file would quiesce ultimately as a valid fixed-point text rendering of the source, of the source, of the source of that URI and most definitely NOT a blank page as done in:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux i686; rv:71.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/71.0
```

**But**

```
Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux i686; rv:77.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/77.0
                             via the scURIple:
data:text/html,<!DOCTYPE html><html contenteditable><pre>
      <script>javascript:document.write(navigator.userAgent);</script>
```

is **even worse** as

```
view-source:view-source:data:text/plain,testing
```

now triggers a web search engine!

The fear is that FF will no longer demonstrate or have the profound tightness of rigorous computational consistency and adherence to the disciplines of recursive function theory and functional programming language design exemplified by the science of computing.

FF functionality is so inconsistent and no longer epitomizes state of the art that it is time to switch to reliability and Forget Fighting FF Forced Funerary Functionality.

---

In particular:

```
javascript: ra=[1,2,3]; ra[1]=ra; ar=eval(ra.toSource()); ar[1]=2; ([ar,ra]).toSource();
```

was a most profound way to *clone* an array (object) with *impunity*.
So `.toSource()` and `uneval()` have also been rendered impotent.

Brendan Eich's initial code was profoundly elegant, and though undocumented a special syntax existed for recursive data structures (eat your heart out JSON).

```
javascript: ra=[1,2,3]; ra[1]=ra;  ra.toSource();
```

would render as

```
#1 = [1,#1#,3]
```

when `window.navigator.userAgent` is

```
Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.2.3) Gecko/20100423 Ubuntu/10.04 (lucid) Firefox/3.6.3,
Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux i686; rv:11.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/11.0
                          or even
Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.0.4) Gecko/2008102920 Firefox/3.0.4 (Splashtop-v1.2.17.0)
```

or FF V <61 (I think) and back to the days of 1994's NetScape, JavaScript 1.2.

ref:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171407/implementing-mozillas-tosource-method-in-internet-explorer/5628008#5628008